# Having trouble submitting Jquerys datepicker into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

It worked before I used the `datepicker`, when I wrote in the date manually into a input field like this: `2016-01-10`. But when I switched to `datepicker` the data are not submitted for some reason.

My html form:

```
     <form class="w3-container">

            <p>
            <label>Titel:</label>
            <input class="w3-input" type="text" id="eTitel"></p>

            <p>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <input class="w3-input" type="text" id="eDesc"></p>

            <p>
            <label>From:</label>
            <input class="w3-input" type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1"></p>

            <p>
            <label>To:</label>
            <input class="w3-input" type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2"></p>

            <br>
            <input type="button" id="button2" value="add+">

         </form>
```

My php code:

```
 <php

       if(isset($_POST["titel"]) && strlen($_POST["titel"])> 0 &&  isset($_POST["descritption"]) && strlen($_POST["descritption"])> 0 && isset($_POST["date"]) && strlen($_POST["date"])> 0 && isset($_POST["todate"]) && strlen($_POST["todate"])> 0){
         $u_id = 1;
        $titel = $_POST["titel"];
         $descritption = $_POST["descritption"];
        $date = $_POST["date"];
       $todate = $_POST["todate"];


        $postInsert2 = $link-> query("INSERT INTO Experiences (u_id, titel, descritption, date, todate) VALUES ('$u_id','$titel','$descritption','$date','$todate' )");
           if($postInsert2){
               echo "succefully inserted into Experiences";
               $link->close();

           }

  }

 ?>
```

My javascript code is:

```
    <script>
$(function() { $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({

    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',


    });
     $("#datepicker1").on("change",function(){
     date = $(this).val();
    alert(date);
});

});

$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({

    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

    });
     $("#datepicker2").on("change",function(){
     todate = $(this).val();
    alert(todate);
  });

});

     $("#button2").click(function(){

     var titel = $("#eTitel").val();
     var descritption = $("#eDesc").val();
    var date = $('input[name=datepicker1]');
    var todate = $('input[name=datepicker2]');

     if(titel == " " && descritption == " " && date == " " && todate == " ")
     {
         alert("values are missing");
     }

     else{
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url: "olle.php",
             data:{

                titel: titel,
                descritption: descritption,
                date: date,
                todate: todate,

             },
             success: function (msg){

                 $("#eTitel").val("");
                 $("#eDesc").val("");
                 $("#datepicker1").val("");
                 $("#datepicker2").val("");
             },
             error: function(){

                 alert("error didnt insert");

             }

         });

     }

 });



    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works when you manually set the date value in the yyyy-mm-dd format, first thing to check would be that the value being acquired from the datepicker is also in this format.  Looking at your datepicker configuration, what jumps out at me is that you have the format set to yy-mm-dd.  Maybe change that to yyyy-mm-dd?  Standard SQL will expect dates in yyyy-mm-dd format when setting their values.